# How do I fix Uneven TempDB Files?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I recently added more CPU cores to a SQL Server and as best practices advise, I separated out the tempDB files into the same number of cores(8).

Also along with best practices, I expanded the size of the new tempdb files, limited auto-growth and shrunk the original files to match the size of the new files.

The problem is, since I was going from a single core to 8 cores, all of the tempdb data remained in the first file, which wouldn't allow me to shrink.  Now I have one tempdb file that is larger than the others and I would like to change that.

I suspect to fix this it will require an outage.

1. Is there a way to do this without an outage?
2. Is this problem even worth addressing?  I know what best practices say, but does this instance really cause any practical problems other than ugliness?

Comment: Do you have scheduled patching in the near future that will include a server restart?

Comment: @JamesJenkins. If only it was that simple.  We run 24/7.  The last couple times I have scheduled an outage, I had to cancel because the business cannot afford to be down, even for an hour.  It has been months since our last official outage.  Since our infrastructure manager doesn't know how to control Windows updates, it will probably restart on it's own any day now.  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EMPTYFILE is just there is transfer *all* the pages to other files, so you subsequently can do ALTER DATABASE ... REMOVE FILE. This doesn't seem to be what we want here.

I wouldn't worry about this, just let it sort itself at next re-start. Remember that tempdb is re-created based on what sys.master_files says. This is the "template" for tempdb regarding number, placement, size etc of the files.

You adjust the size in sys.master_files using ALTER DATABASE ... MODIFY FILE. If you want help, just use SSMS, tempdb, properties, and adjust the size for any of the tempdb files to a *larger* size. Then script the command and adjust to your liking. (The reason to not specify a smaller size in the GUI is that it will generate a DBCC SHRINKFILE, which only (tries) to address the current size for tempdb and does nothing for the template. It is perfectly possible to specify a smaller size than current size using ALTER DATABASE for tempdb as it will only affect the "template" and not the current size.

Answer (score 1):

So since I don't know the size of the tempdb you are working on, I will make an example.
[image: Database Files Layout]

Make sure to set auto growth all files on the file group.

```
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES
```

So to make the files the same size I would shrink tempdev to 30000MB like the rest of the files.
I would do that in in crements so the shrink can be stoped and restarted without the work so far wasted.

```
USE [tempdb]
DECLARE @FileName sysname = N'tempdev';
DECLARE @TargetSize INT = (SELECT 1 + size*8./1024 FROM sys.database_files WHERE name = @FileName);
DECLARE @Factor FLOAT = .999;
 
WHILE @TargetSize > 30000
BEGIN
    SET @TargetSize *= @Factor;
    DBCC SHRINKFILE(@FileName, @TargetSize);
    DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(200) = CONCAT('Shrink file completed. Target Size: ', 
         @TargetSize, ' MB. Timestamp: ', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    RAISERROR(@msg, 1, 1) WITH NOWAIT;
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
END;
```

If I got blocked by a page I would try to see if it is anything I could release.

```
USE [tempdb]
GO
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
GO
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
GO
DBCC FREESESSIONCACHE
GO
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ( 'ALL')
GO
```

And then I would start the shrink again.

If it is still blocked by a page, then I would set the initial file size so the file will be the same size after next sql service restart.

```
ALTER DATABASE TempDB MODIFY FILE
(NAME = tempdev, SIZE = 30000MB )
GO
```